# Xcode 5 crashes on new project creation

Tags: xcode

I can't create new projects in Xcode 5. This is for any type of project, and the IDE crashes without any error messages the moment I hit ***Create*** button for the new project after filling up the project information. I don't even know where to start looking for to fix this.

I think I created one new project last week, had no issues up until today. One clue might be, this last time I checked the box saying "Create git repository on...", right on top of the ***Create*** button in the ***Create new project*** section in Xcode. Doesn't matter if I uncheck that now, and from Xcode preferences, disabling source control doesn't help either.

I deleted the plist file in preferences folder, that didn't help. I deleted xcode, and reinstalled it from the app store, that didn't help either.

I can jump into existing projects, build them and also run them in simulators successfuly.

Anyone encountered a similar issue and what could be the fix?

**EDIT**: I was able to get an error message for one of the project templates, for empty projects this error is produced;

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending ok: to <NSOpenPanel: 0x7fc1a40730b0> from <NSButton: 0x7fc1a40c27e0>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-3591/Framework/Classes/Templates/IDETemplateInstantiationContext.m:145
Details:  Assertion failed: [instantiatedItems count] == 1
```

Comment: Is anything written to the Console? Perhaps that could point you to a bad file or something?

Comment: Nope nothing is written in terminal. If you mean the Xcode console, I can't get to that point to see anything because of the crash happens on create project action and Xcode terminates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try deleting Xcode's preferences file (from common and user library both) and restart Xcode -

/Library/Preferences

com.apple.dt.Xcode

/Users/*YourUsername*/Library/Preferences
( I have following 3 files related to Xcode there )

com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist

com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist.BoGEJ0T

Couple of other troubleshootings that I would suggest are -

1. Try choosing another project template (iOS or Cocoa/Mac application etc).
2. Use XCode through another user on this machine (create one if you don't have).

Comment: No template works for iOS or Mac, I'll try switching out the user account and see. Tnx

Comment: Deleting preferences worked! I deleted only this location before; /Library/Preferences which didn't work. But that location plus /Users/YourUsername/Library/Preferences and deleting the three files in there worked. Ty

Answer (score 1):

This [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23567487?tstart=0#23567487?tstart=0) resolved the problem.

```
sudo find / -name '.DS_Store' -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened again today and the solution worked before for me didn't work this time. Also tried to run the sudo code mentioned here but nothing.

So how I solved it this time was on project creation where I choose a folder to save the new files. I chose another directory that I was using before to save files and it worked just like that way.

So this issue might be related to a directory problem Xcode glitches on sometimes. Different solutions work to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I am running xcode 5.0.1 and have the same issue. I solved the problem. Try to name you project with a "dot" end ( for example: name of project "VuNguyen.") then the button Next appear. Then you could delete the "dot" in your project name. This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me. However, it was because the target directory I was placing the project in was locked.