# xcode 5.0.1 crashes when I build and run an empty ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash

Xcode 5.0.1 crashes when I build and run an empty ios app.

How i can solve this?

**And the Log are as follows:**

```
Version:         5.0.1 (3335.23)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335023000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [192]
Responsible:     Xcode [600]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-03-17 19:36:09.442 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FC8475E3-7090-9E79-B7E3-A079F66EB066


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fb1ae158e50> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fb1ae158e50>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A2053
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'workerClass' of extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the **Mavericks** OS from the App Store and reinstall my OS which was also **Mavericks** OS before.

After I finished it, every user files and apps just remain intact and the most important,

I solve the crashing problem.

Hope this will help others who have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps:**

1. Close all open applications
2. relaunch Finder
3. run  sudo find / -name ".DS_Store"  -exec rm {} \; This removes all  .DS_Store old files on the computer
4. Launch finder and set default view to "LIST VIEW" as shown here: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/ss/Setting-Finder-Views-For-Folders-And-Sub-Folders_2.htm
5. Rerun the offending application and file chooser works

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Kindly check out these links: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23503629#23503629   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473231/xcode-5-crashes-on-new-project-creation

Comment: I have done the steps listed above, but find that it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You welcome, then I suggest you to download latest and stable version of Xcode from App store your problem will solve.

Comment: I have tried different versions of **xCode** from 4.6 to 5.0.1 to 5.1. But they all crashed the same way as before. It seems that there are some problem with my **os**. @Irfan

Comment: Guess what? I downloaded the **mavericks** from the App Store and reinstall my OS which was also **mavericks** before. After I finished it, every user files and apps just remain intact and the most important, I solve the crashing problem!!