# Can't create Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

For some reason, every time I try to create an Xcode project, I get stuck in this spinning wheel screen:

[image: Image showing a spinning wheel in the center of the screen]

I tried this solution, and that didn't work.
[Xcode won't let me create a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534726/xcode-wont-let-me-create-a-new-project)

I also tried this solution, but that didn't work either.
[Xcode 5 crashes on new project creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473231/xcode-5-crashes-on-new-project-creation)

I tried reinstalling Xcode twice, but I keep getting the same thing. Any other ideas?

Comment: What version of Xcode might we be talking about?

Comment: Is your git repo full?

Comment: I don't know how to find that out

Comment: Try it on another computer? Or, if you don't have one, try making a new user, perhaps, and log into that user and see if it works any better there. I'm wondering whether something about your prefs is hosed.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Please, let me know if you find a solution, will do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Organization identifier, otherwise Xcode won't create the project.